# Parse Play 2 json form errors using Prickle in Scala.js

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js

I'm trying to convert JSON with Play 2 form errors to case classes in Scala.js.
Here is result from server:

> {"obj.comment":[{"msg":["error.minLength"],"args":[10]}],"obj.name":[{"msg":["error.path.missing"],"args":[]}]}

Here is my code from Scala.js:

```
import prickle._
sealed trait Result
case class fmData(name: String, comment: String)
case class MsgData(msg: Array[String], args: Array[Int]) extends Result
case class MyResult(`obj.comment`: Array[MsgData], `obj.name`: Array[MsgData]) extends Result
implicit val resultPickler: PicklerPair[Result] = CompositePickler[Result].concreteType[MsgData].concreteType[MyResult]
```

just trying to do everything like in the example from https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle
But I got error on compilation stage with error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter p:
>   prickle.Pickler[MsgData] [error]     implicit val resultPickler:
>   PicklerPair[Result] =
>   CompositePickler[Result].concreteType[MsgData].concreteType[MyResult]
>   [error]
>   ^

Can't understand why I need to provide Pickler for MsgData. There is no Pickler for concreteType in the example.

How this issue can be fixed?